# Десктоп-установщик electronjs вместе с клиентом postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Необходимо собрать установщик electronjs внутри которого будет установщик postgres. Или как то инициировал загрузку клиента postgres с возможностью конфигурировать как то клиент. Очень трудно найти информацию об этом в интернете, пишут что установщик нужно ставить отдельно и настраивать дальше, но ведь как то же собирают приложения для десктоп.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для создания установщика можно воспользоваться программой [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) - это свободное ПО, можно пользоваться бесплатно.

Для более удобной работы с Inno Setup существует [Inno Script Studio](https://www.kymoto.org/products/inno-script-studio) - ставится поверх Inno Setup, позволяет создавать установщик без написания скриптов за счёт использования мастеров (wizard).

Основы работы с Inno Setup можно прочитать в [этой](https://habr.com/post/255807/) статье на Хабре.

Как работать с Inno Script Studio можно посмотреть [здесь](https://golos.io/ru--obrazovanie/@zaguzin/razrabotka-installyatorov-urok-14-inno-setup-vvedenie-ustanovka-i-prostoi-proekt).